# Make {parenthesis} a synonym of {parentheses}

Tags: discussion, tagging

**Stats on the two tags** (as of time of writing):

[parenthesis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parenthesis): 33 questions total, 2 unanswered, no tag wiki written

[parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parentheses): 30 questions total, 3 unanswered, well-written tag wiki

I came across this when retagging one of the questions on TeX.SE involving parentheses. Considering how these two terms are just singular/plural forms of each other, I suggest we make them synonyms.

Comment: Good idea, I'd support that.

Comment: I'm surprised they aren't synonyms yet!

Comment: People (with enough rep) could vote to make these synonyms to brackets by voting here https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/brackets/synonyms

Answer (score 9):

Actually you might consider making them both aliases for [brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brackets)  which covers much the same ground, for example this question only has the brackets tag and has parenthesis in the title

[Universal Parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360996/universal-parentheses)

Comment: Apparently, {parentheses} has been proposed to be a synonym for {brackets} on Sep'15, but it's status is (still?) pending? [(See here)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) Does it usually take this long to get synonyms approved? haha

Comment: @Troy: I've always found that suggested synonyms are best resolved by also asking on [meta.tex.se].